# Do I use a comma between "whimsical" and "clay" in the sentence below?

Tags: adjectives, comma-splices

> Billy did a wonderful job creating his whimsical[,] clay fish dish.

Comment: Is it a dish in the shape of a fish?  Or is it a dish for eating fish out of?  Interesting either way.

Answer (score 4):

I respectfully disagree with Konrad's answer.

From http://www.grammarmudge.cityslide.com/board/board_topic/3845648/1159442.htm:

When two adjectives precede a noun, the first adjective may modify the combined idea of the second adjective plus the noun. In such cases do not separate the adjectives by a comma.

—The estate is surrounded by an old stone wall. (A 'stone' wall that is 'old'.)
—Here is the annual financial statement. (A 'financial' statement that is 'annual'.)

TEST: To decide whether consecutive adjectives should be separated by a comma or not, try using them in a relative clause after the noun, with 'and' inserted between them. If they read smoothly and sensibly in that position, they should be separated by a comma in their actual position.

—We need an intelligent, enterprising person for the job. (One can speak of 'a person who is intelligent and enterprising, so a comma is correct.)
—Throw out your old down coat. (One cannot speak of 'a coat that is old and down, so no comma should be used in the sentence.)

**Whimsical clay fish dish** is like **old stone wall**; the stone wall is old, and the clay fish dish is whimsical.

The website http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2012/10/commas-with-adjectives-before-nouns.html concurs:

Here are several tests to recognize equal adjectives:

1. Insert **and** between them. If the sentence still flows smoothly and makes sense, the comma is correct.

Thank you for your helpful and detailed report. (Flows smoothly and makes sense. Needs the comma when **and** is omitted.)
Thank you for your helpful and monthly report. (Does not make sense because it sounds like two reports. The adjectives are not equal and do not need a comma when **and** is omitted.

You would not say **whimsical and clay fish dish**, so no comma is needed.

The websites http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000072.htm and http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-adjectives add an additional proof:

If you can reverse the order of the adjectives, use the comma.  Consider the above example, **We need an intelligent, enterprising person for the job.**  You could just as easily say **We need an enterprising, intelligent person for the job.**  Use the comma (or **and**).

But you can't say **clay whimsical fish dish**, so no comma.

Comment: This is a comprehensively good answer. However another point seems to me to concern whether the dish is in the shape of a fish, or whether it is a dish for eating fish. If the former I would hyphenate *clay-fish*. Without the hyphen I would assume it to be a dish for eating fish.

Comment: A fish dish can be three things, as far as I can tell:  1) A type of meal containing fish, like dill salmon or broiled trout.  Since this type of fish dish cannot be made of clay, we can eliminate it.  2) A plate for serving fish on, which is generally shaped like a fish (or why would it be used just for fish?), and 3) a plate shaped like a fish, which obviously would be used for, well, serving fish.  Thus, 2 and 3 are one and the same; hence, no ambiguity.  And "clay-fish" sounds like a fish made of, or having characteristics of clay.  No one would want to eat that.  I'd omit the hyphen.

Comment: I accept a lot of what you say. But to my mind a dish made out of clay in the shape of a fish could be used for many things, only one of which might be for serving/eating fish from. It could, for example, be merely ornamental.

Comment: I think that if the dish were shaped as a fish and were meant to be strictly ornamental (which to me seems unlikely), I'd call it a "fish-shaped dish."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do. Unless the clay is whimsical, not the dish.